# transformations of matrices

Tags: 3d, matrix, transformation

I'm in the process of [reading up on 3d matrices](http://www.sjbaker.org/steve/omniv/matrices_can_be_your_friends.html) and trying to following [this powerpoint](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CE8QxQEwAg&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2Fviewer%3Fa%3Dv%26q%3Dcache%3ABe-OV4Ke2t0J%3Aresearch.cs.wisc.edu%2Fgraphics%2FCourses%2F559-s2001%2Flectures%2Flecture-9-online.ppt%2B%26hl%3Den%26gl%3Dus%26pid%3Dbl%26srcid%3DADGEESj5pljiuCb66xTVL_LvEwB5UKOtgDIEQnFZBCgtQOl5rMcL-6-n2VPwCl18JcbIDADLRCs555BJoHq3y-_JQiBXgK0yAFudL529QEJ1lgdiLN-N01FRx8gtr689LjdoNdmZzFZf%26sig%3DAHIEtbTn369SuPw_cPWTImX1yXldXUtwiw&ei=HtFUUfPHCbOFyQGwpICICA&usg=AFQjCNGHhG-5DYfQE41NgRW9Q5tzw3oITw&sig2=8jtR4nmLGubbIpTzKyj5Vw&bvm=bv.44442042,d.aWc) and had a few questions as to how to exactly determine the type of transformation from a matrix.

If I have a matrix such as...

```
a 0 0
0 b 0
0 0 1
```

or

```
1 0 a
0 1 b
0 0 1
```

...would these be considered a translation by (a, b) vector?

Or a matrix such as...

```
cos(a) -sin(a)   0 
sin(a)  cos(a)   0
  0        0     1
```

... would this be considered rotation about Z-axis through the angle `a`?

Is there a better way to visualize these?

Comment: Do you want to represent linear transformations in 3D or affine transformations in 2D? If linear in 3D, there is no translation! if affine in 2D, there is no Z-axis!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to gain intuition about how a matrix behaves is by determining its effect on the standard basis vectors:

```
     1        0        0
e1 = 0   e2 = 1   e3 = 0
     0        0        1
```

Since any 3D vector can be written as a combination of `a*e1 + b*e2 + c*e3`, if we know how  a matrix changes these three vectors, we know how a matrix changes any vector.

So, to start off, let's examine the first matrix you have:

```
    a 0 0
M = 0 b 0
    0 0 1
```

We can see that

```
         a              0              0
e1 * M = 0     e2 * M = b     e3 * M = 0
         0              0              1
```

Hence, we see that `e1` gets scaled by `a`, `e2` gets scaled by `b`, and `e3` stays the same. Since we don't know whether or not `a` equals `b`, or even if they are equal to one, this is a skew matrix.

If we perform a similar analysis to the matrix

```
    1 0 a
M = 0 1 b
    0 0 1
```

we see that `e1` and `e2` do not change, but `e3` changes drastically. This means that every vector in the `XY` plane will remain the same, but every vector that has a nonzero `z` coordinate will become distorted! So, to answer your question, neither of these are translation matrices.

As your intuition might tell you by this point, you cannot translate a 3D vector using only 3x3 matrices. For that you need to use [homogeneous coordinates](http://www.cim.mcgill.ca/~langer/558/2009/lecture3.pdf).

I would suggest you go through these steps with the last matrix you have written. Spoiler alert: it is indeed a rotation about the z-axis.

Comment: The second one could be a 2D translation in homogeneous cords, an *affine* transformation.